# Adding empty json object in a pre-existing JSON Object and after a given json object index - Php

Tags: php, mysql, json

so I have an Array of JSON Objects generated from mysql query.

JSON Object looks like:

```
[
  {"field1": "value1", "field2": "value2"},
  {"field1": "value3", "field2": "value4"},
  {"field1": "value5", "field2": "value6"},
  {"field1": "value7", "field2": "value8"}
]
```

now I want to add empty object like this: `{}` after 3rd JSON object in the array.

expected result:

```
[
  {"field1": "value1", "field2": "value2"},
  {"field1": "value3", "field2": "value4"},
  {"field1": "value5", "field2": "value6"},
  {},
  {"field1": "value7", "field2": "value8"}
]
```

I am able to loop through each json object and I am able to replace the current object's value but not sure how to add a whole new json empty object.

## My code

```
for($j = 0; $j < $length; $j++) {

            if($j == 1 ){
                // HERE I dont want to replace Jth JSON Obj but add new empty Obj, something like $data.push('{}')
                $data[$j]['field1'] = '';
                $data[$j]['field2'] = '';
            }else{
                $data[$j]['question'] = $ques_arr[$j];
                $data[$j]['response'] = $allresponses[$j]['response'];
            }
        }
```

Comment: try `array_splice` and `new stdClass()`

Comment: @Fei Can you show an example of what u mean by `stdClass()` ?

Comment: `array_splice($data,$j,0,new stdClass())` this will insert an empty object at $j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add it via `new \StdClass()`OR `[(object)[]]` as example

```
$test = '[
{"field1": "value1", "field2": "value2"},
{"field1": "value3", "field2": "value4"},
{"field1": "value5", "field2": "value6"},
{"field1": "value7", "field2": "value8"}
]';
 $temp = json_decode($test);
 array_splice($temp, 3, 0, new \StdClass());
$result = json_encode($temp);
var_dump($result);
```

return `[{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"},{"field1":"value3","field2":"value4"},{},{"field1":"value7","field2":"value8"}]`

**update**
Use [`array_splice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) and try :

```
    $test = '[
{"field1": "value1", "field2": "value2"},
{"field1": "value3", "field2": "value4"},
{"field1": "value5", "field2": "value6"},
{"field1": "value7", "field2": "value8"}
]';
    $temp = json_decode($test);
    $value = (new \StdClass());
    array_splice($temp, 3, 0, [(object)[]]);
    $result = json_encode($temp,true);
    var_dump($result);
```

as you wanted.

Comment: You have replaced the third Json Object to empty {}. I dont want to replace it but add a new object

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia I resolved it, check my answer again plz.

Answer (score 3):

```
    $json = '[
    {"field1": "value1", "field2": "value2"},
    {"field1": "value3", "field2": "value4"},
    {"field1": "value5", "field2": "value6"},
    {"field1": "value7", "field2": "value8"}
    ]';
    $temp = json_decode($json);
    $inserted = array( (object)[]);
    array_splice( $temp, 3, 0, $inserted );
    $result = json_encode($temp);
    var_dump($result);
```